# JavaScript Date Comparisons Don't Equal

Tags: javascript, date, equality

I've tried searching for people with similar questions, but haven't found anything.

I have two dates in JavaScript, both set to the same value... Equality Testing fails on ==, but >= and <= evaluate true.

Below is the code I have in play:

```
var startDate = new Date( 2011, 7, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0 );

var dt = new Date( 2011, 7, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0 );

if( startDate == dt )
    document.write('They Equal<br />');

if( startDate > dt )
    document.write('Start Date is > dt<br />');

if( startDate >= dt )
    document.write('Start Date is >= dt<br />');

if( startDate < dt )
    document.write('Start Date is < dt<br />');

if( startDate <= dt )
    document.write('Start Date is <= dt<br />');

if( dt == startDate )
    document.write('They Equal<br />');

if( dt > startDate )
    document.write('dt > startDate<br />');

if( dt >= startDate )
    document.write('dt >= Start Date <br />');

if( dt < startDate )
    document.write('dt < Start Date <br />');

if( dt <= startDate )
    document.write('dt <= Start Date <br />');  

document.write( dt );
document.write( '<br />');
document.write( startDate );
```

Has anyone encountered anything like this, or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

I tested this is Internet Explorer (9), Firefox 5+, and Chrome.

**Update:**

So two people posted great answers to my problem, and I thank both of you: xdazz and DaveRandom. I had read an earlier post on stackoverflow.com on a similar question and a guy said that date objects could be compared like any others, and any other example I found always did a < or > type of compare, never a full equality so I wasn't able to make the connection as to why I was doing it wrong.

Thanks to you two, and the others that posted similar answers.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

When you use `<=` or `>=` to compare two date objects, they are compared  via `valueOf`, which is the same as `getTime` for Date.

But when you use `==`, they are two different objects of the same type, so it returns false.

Added some examples:

```
> new Date(2011, 7, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0) == new Date( 2011, 7, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0 )
false
> new Date(2011, 7, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0).getTime() == new Date( 2011, 7, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0).getTime()
true
> new Date(2011, 7, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0).valueOf() == new Date( 2011, 7, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0).valueOf()
true
> new Date(2011, 7, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0).valueOf() == new Date( 2011, 7, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0).getTime()
true
```

Answer (score 54):

I think if you do

```
var startDate = (new Date( 2011, 7, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0 )).getTime();
var dt = (new Date( 2011, 7, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0 )).getTime();
```

At the top of the script you will find it works.

The `getTime()` method returns the date as an integer, what you are doing there is comparing objects, rather than specific values.

**EDIT** Fixed above code

Comment: @Shef Only by about 50 seconds, and I'll give you a +1 for your troubles ;-)

Answer (score 21):

This is one of the many illogical parts of Javascript. You can work around this problem by converting the date to a number using `.getTime()` that will return how many milliseconds passed from that date and 00:00:00 of Jan 1, 1970.

```
if (a.getTime() === b.getTime()) ...
```

The `===` operator on the objects themselves will return always false because those two objects are indeed distinct mutable javascript objects.

PS: Don't use `==` operator with Javascript. Ever. What it does takes the term "crazy" to a whole new level. Seriously. The problem is that applies all sort of type conversions that simply make no sense and for example you end up with things like `"1"==1`, `x==false && (x?1:2)==1` or even `a==b && b==c && a!=c` being true (e.g. with `x=[]` or with `a=[1], b=1, c=[[1]]`). Just don't use `==`. Ever. It's "FUBAR". Fullstop.

Comment: I mostly agree with the postscript, but it should be supported with something far more meaningful, like this: http://www.2ality.com/2011/12/strict-equality-exemptions.html

Comment: @MichaelScheper: I agree that that article is a nice analysis of many allegedly valid use cases, but I think it's important to also point out why it can be very dangerous (i.e. that `==` is not transitive, or that you can have `x == false` but `x` being truthy).

Answer (score 8):

```
var startDate = new Date( 2011, 7, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0 );

var dt = new Date( 2011, 7, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0 );

if( startDate.getTime() == dt.getTime() )
    console.log('They Equal<br />');
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<Script>
function checkval()
{
var strfromdate=document.frmadmin.txtfromdate.value;
strfromdate=strfromdate.split("/");
//alert(strfromdate[2]+" "+strfromdate[0]+" "+strfromdate[1]);

var strtodate=document.frmadmin.txttodate.value;
strtodate=strtodate.split("/");

var fromDate = (new Date( strfromdate[2], strfromdate[0], strfromdate[1], 0, 0, 0, 0 )).getTime();
var toDate = (new Date( strtodate[2], strtodate[0], strtodate[1], 0, 0, 0, 0 )).getTime();
//alert(fromDate+" "+toDate);



    if(toDate<fromDate)
    {
        alert("To date should be greater than from date.");
        document.frmadmin.txttodate.focus();
        return false;
    }


    return true;
}
</Script>
```