# Even the date values are same, but fail to get logger

Tags: google-apps-script

I just encountered some weird thing ... but can't really find the reason...
I used google apps script and tried to compare the values by using for() and if().
The weird thing is that.. Even though the code that I used is same, the results were different.

I got four 'A's when compared the B column but no results(logs) when compared D column..

For better understanding, I put data capture and my codes below..
Could anyone help me to solve this issue?

[image]

```js
function leaveM(){

var log = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('abc');

//get 'B' column's last text value
var name = log.getRange(log.getLastRow(),2).getValue();

//get 'D' column's last date value
var addDate = log.getRange(log.getLastRow(),4).getValue();

var data = log.getDataRange().getValues();

for(var u=1; u<data.length; u++){

   if(data[u][1] == name){

     Logger.log(data[u][1]);

}

}

for(var u=1; u<data.length; u++){

  if( data[u][3] == addDate){

    Logger.log(data[u][3]);

  }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are comparing two date objects. This is covered in numerous posts
[JavaScript Date Comparisons Don't Equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244513/javascript-date-comparisons-dont-equal)