# Comparing two same dates in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, date, datetime

I tried comparing 2 same dates in the chrome console:

new Date("2021-06-23") == new Date("2021-06-23")

It is giving false

new Date("2021-06-23") > new Date("2021-06-23")

It is giving false

But, new Date("2021-06-23") >= new Date("2021-06-23")

It is giving true

I couldn't understand why it is giving true for greater than or equal to but false for both greater than also and for equals to as well.

Please explain.

Comment: `==` when applied to objects checks if they are *the same object*, not if two different objects but with similar content. Relationship operators instead do implicit conversion.

Comment: ^ This. By contrast, `Date` objects have defined behaviour for `>/>=/</<=` operators that compares the date value.

Comment: I should also point out that since you aren't defining the time portion of the date, there's no guarantee that `new Date("2021-06-23") == new Date("2021-06-23")` would be true anyway, as the millisecond may change between calls.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript Date Object Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606798/javascript-date-object-comparison). Also see [JavaScript Date Comparisons Don't Equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244513/javascript-date-comparisons-dont-equal).

Comment: Try `new Date("2021-06-23").getTime() === new Date("2021-06-23").getTime();` the `getTime()` will get the `UNIX Timestamp` value.

Comment: you are comparing 2 objects, whatever their contains

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol if a ISO date string is passed then the milliseconds will be initialised to zero.

Answer (score 0):

The Date object don't support grater or equal operators per se... It has something like [Symbol.toPrimitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive)

It's a function that gets called when it should be converted to the appropriated primitive value

```js
const object1 = {
  [Symbol.toPrimitive](hint) {
    if (hint === 'number') {
      return 42;
    }
    return null;
  }
};

console.log(+object1);
// expected output: 42
```

So if you want to compare if two dates are equals then you can do

`+new Date() === +new Date()`

when you use any of this operators `+ - * / < >` then it wishes to convert it to a number so you are actually comparing numbers and not objects

Comment: A better reference is [ECMA-262 *Abstract Relational Comparison Algorithm*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison), which uses the plain [*ToPrimitive*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-toprimitive) abstract operation. [*Symbol.ToPrimitive*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/fundamental-objects.html#sec-symbol.toprimitive) is specifically for Symbol objects, not Date objects.

Answer (score 0):

Because `new Date` create an unique object.

Even if they have the sames properties, 2 distinct objects will never been equals.

```js
const x = {a : "aaa"};
const y = {a : "aaa"};

console.log(x == y); // false

const z = x; // litteraly the same object

console.log(x == z); // true
```